# Local variable referenced before assignment (don't want to use global)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning Python using "Learn Python the hard way" and am currently making a simple game

Following the book's guidelines, each "room" is to be it's own function and herein lies my problem, I have some variables that need to be accessed by all functions. e.g. Current_health, armor, strength stat.

I have looked at the previous questions on here (that I actually understood) and the only solution seems to be to declare it as a global variable within the function, but as I'm going to have 20+ rooms (functions) it seems a bit silly to declare them all every time

The other option is to pass the variable when calling the function, but as I need to put through 8 variables each time that also seems impractical. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll paste the code below in case it helps (the game is far from finished so some may not make sense)

Right now the start() works because of my global variables but I'll run into the error as soon as it tries to run shadow_figure() because of the wep_dam reference

```
from sys import exit

str = 0
wep_dam = 0
dam = str + wep_dam
cha = 0
sne = 0
arm = 0
max_life = 10
points_remaining = 0

def shadow_figure():
    print "\n\nYou approach the figure, who remains silent."
    print "As you get closer you realise he has bag at his feet."
    print "Mysterious figure: \"You may choose only one.\""
    print "You look into the bag, and see a shiny sword on top of a large steel shield."
    ans = raw_input("Do you: \n1. Take the sword \n2. Take the shield \n3. Take the whole bag and run \n4. Walk away without taking anything\n> ")
    if ans == "1":
        print "The sword gives you an extra 3 damage"
        wep_dam += 3
        exit_beach()
    elif ans == "2":
        print "The shield gives you 3 armor, but it's so heavy it reduces your sneak by 1"
        arm += 3
        sne -= 1


def beach():
    print "\n\nYou wake up on a beach with no idea how you got there. \nYou see a shadowy figure close to the water."
    ans = raw_input("Do you: \n1. Approach him \n2. Go the other way\n> ")
    if ans == "1":
        shadow_figure()
    elif ans == "2":
        exit_beach()
    else:
        print "Please enter either 1 or 2"

def reset_stats():
    str = 0
    wep_dam = 0
    dam = str + wep_dam
    cha = 0
    sne = 0
    arm = 0

    max_life = 10

    points_remaining = 10
    print "\n\n\n\nGame Reset\n\n\n\n"


def start():
    global str
    global wep_dam
    global dam
    global cha
    global sne
    global arm
    str = 0
    wep_dam = 0
    dam = str + wep_dam
    cha = 0
    sne = 0
    arm = 0

    max_life = 10
    points_remaining = 0

    print "You are an adventurer, your stats are currently:"
    print "Strength:  %d \nCharisma:  %d \n  Sneak:   %d" % ( str,  cha,  sne)
    print "Strength determines your damage, charisma determines your chance of pursuasion, \nand sneak determines whether or not you can go get past enemies without being detected"
    print "you have 10 points available to spend, to spend a point, simply type the number which corresponds\nwith the skill and hit enter"
    print "\n\n1. Strength \t2. Charisma \t3. Sneak\n"
    points_remaining = 10
    while points_remaining > 0:
        ans = raw_input("Choose a skill: ")
        if ans == "1":
            str += 1
            points_remaining -= 1
            print "Strength is now  %d" % ( str)
            print "%d  points remaining\n" % ( points_remaining)

        elif ans == "2":
            cha += 1
            points_remaining -= 1
            print "Charisma is now %d" % ( cha)
            print "%d points remaining\n" % ( points_remaining)

        elif ans == "3":
            sne += 1
            points_remaining -= 1
            print "Sneak is now %d" % ( sne)
            print "%d points remaining\n" % (points_remaining)
        else:
            print "Error, please enter a number from 1 to 3\n"

    print "Your stats are now: "
    print "Strength:  %d \nCharisma:  %d \n   Sneak:  %d\n\n" % ( str,  cha,  sne)
    print "Is this OK? Or would you like to restart?\n"
    ans = raw_input("1. Continue \n2. Restart\n> ")
    if ans == "1":
        print "Game will now begin...."
        beach()
    elif ans == "2":
        ans = raw_input("Are you sure? Yes/No\n> ")
        ans = ans.lower()
        if ans == "yes":
            reset_stats()
            start()
        else:
            beach()
    else:
        print "Error, please enter 1 or 2"


start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap your globals in `class`:

```
class Player:
    str = 0
    wep_dam = 0
    dam = str + wep_dam
    cha = 0
    sne = 0
    arm = 0
    max_life = 10
    points_remaining = 0
```

and access its fields in rooms like this: `Player.arm += 3`

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Now to work on this Indentation error I'm getting after making this change...